# Displaying custom value formats in HTML input field

Tags: html

I am working with a phone number field on my form...

```
<label for="phone_no">Phone:</label>
<input name="phone_no" placeholder="(555)867-5309" type="tel" value="<?php print($_POST['phone_no']); ?>"/>
```

I want this number to be an integer, so I'm using type="tel". Is it possible to "mask" the data (i.e. display it formatted without actually changing the underlying data)?

This would save me from having to programmatically alter it to display it and in turn alter it to interpret it and store it in my database.

P.S. I will also require a similar solution for an SSN field, so please do not make your answer too specific so that it only works with phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, the easiest way to deal with this is just to accept the phone number as a string, and strip any non-alpha characters server-side before storing it in the database.  It is way more trouble that it's worth to try to deal with it client-side as you suggest.

```
function remove_non_numeric($string) {
    return preg_replace('/\D/', '', $string)
}
```

Then you can reject it if it doesn't have 10 characters or however precise you want to be with validating the data.

Displaying it is not terribly difficult either, but you'll find it's easier to do it if you treat the phone number as a string.

Hope this helps.